Precompiling Failed Blazor Wasm
All nuget packages are in the latest version.I get an error when opening AOT at publish time in Blazor Wasm application. I need help. I also use Dev Express package. I don't have any information about AOT support yet, I opened a ticket there too.
.NET Version: 8.0.303
VS 2022 Version: 17.10.5
All nuget packages are in the latest version.
Output Window:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Cl
ient\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [DevExpress.Printing.v24.1.Core.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\ao
  t-in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mon
  o.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\do
  tnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dw
  arfdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\rep
  os\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\DevExpress_Printing_v24_1_Core_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazı
  lım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Printing.v24.1.Core.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gens
  oft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Printing.v24.1.Core.dll.tmp" "DevExpress.Printing.v24.1.Core.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExpress.Printing.v24.1.Core.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GS
YS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazo
r.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [Blazored.LocalStorage.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in: MON
  O_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser
  -wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\pack
  s\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dwarfdebug,
  llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensof
  t.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\Blazored_LocalStorage_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\G
  ensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Blazored.LocalStorage.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client
  \obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Blazored.LocalStorage.dll.tmp" "Blazored.LocalStorage.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Blazored.LocalStorage.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor
.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Drawing.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-
  in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.
  browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotn
  et\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dwar
  fdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos
  \Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\DevExpress_Pdf_v24_1_Drawing_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\
  source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Drawing.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GS
  YS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Drawing.dll.tmp" "DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Drawing.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Drawing.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS
.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [DevExpress.Blazor.v24.1.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in: M
  ONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.brows
  er-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\pa
  cks\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dwarfdebu
  g,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gens
  oft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\DevExpress_Blazor_v24_1_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\rep
  os\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Blazor.v24.1.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\
  Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Blazor.v24.1.dll.tmp" "DevExpress.Blazor.v24.1.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExpress.Blazor.v24.1.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blaz
or.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-pub
  lish\aot-in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runt
  ime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program F
  iles\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=
  simd,dwarfdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\sou
  rce\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_Forms_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\User
  s\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\re
  pos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll.tmp" "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gen
soft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\a
  ot-in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mo
  no.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\d
  otnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,d
  warfdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\re
  pos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Ya
  zılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\G
  ensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll.tmp" "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.G
SYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [DevExpress.Drawing.v24.1.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in:
  MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.brow
  ser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\p
  acks\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dwarfdeb
  ug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gen
  soft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\DevExpress_Drawing_v24_1_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\r
  epos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Drawing.v24.1.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wa
  sm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Drawing.v24.1.dll.tmp" "DevExpress.Drawing.v24.1.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExpress.Drawing.v24.1.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Bla
zor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publis
  h\aot-in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime
  .Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program File
  s\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=sim
  d,dwarfdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source
  \repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gens
  oft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Genso
  ft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll.tmp" "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensof
t.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publi
  sh\aot-in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtim
  e.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Fil
  es\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=si
  md,dwarfdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\sourc
  e\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_Web_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Ge
  nsoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Ge
  nsoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll.tmp" "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll"

  [DevExpress.Data.v24.1.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in: MON
  O_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser
  -wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\pack
  s\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dwarfdebug,
  llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensof
  t.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\DevExpress_Data_v24_1_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\G
  ensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Data.v24.1.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client
  \obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Data.v24.1.dll.tmp" "DevExpress.Data.v24.1.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExpress.Data.v24.1.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor
.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Genso
ft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Core.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in:
   MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.bro
  wser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,mattr=simd,dwarfde
  bug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Ge
  nsoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\DevExpress_Pdf_v24_1_Core_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source
  \repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Core.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor
  .Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Core.dll.tmp" "DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Core.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\DevExpress.Pdf.v24.1.Core.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll] Exec (with response file contents expanded) in C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\f
  or-publish\aot-in: MONO_PATH=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.Ap
  p.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\native\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm\8.0.7\runtimes\browser-wasm\lib\net8.0 MONO_ENV_OPTIONS= C:\Pro
  gram Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm\8.0.7\Sdk\..\tools\mono-aot-cross.exe --wasm-exceptions --debug --llvm "--aot=no-opt,static,direct-icalls,deterministic,
  mattr=simd,dwarfdebug,llvm-path=C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.34.Sdk.win-x64\8.0.7\tools\bin\,static,dedup-skip,trimming-eligible-methods-outfile=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazıl
  ım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\tokens\Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_dll_compiled_methods.txt,llvmonly,interp,asmonly,llvm-out
  file=C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll.bc.tmp,temp-path=C:\Users\Gensoft
  -Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll.tmp" "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll"

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Bl
azor.Wasm\Client\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Clie
nt\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\8.0.7\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(686,5): error : The specified response file can not be read [C:\Users\Gensoft-Yazılım\source\repos\Gensoft
.GSYS\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm\Client\Gensoft.GSYS.Blazor.Wasm.Client.csproj]


I fixed the error. The problem is that there are foreign characters in the name of the location on the computer.
